# Count function returning wrong value when joined

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I am trying to find a count of actions completed along with company details for companies who have more than 10 users.

The code I am using is:

```
SELECT 
    c.company_name,
    count(a.action) as actions,
    count(u.user_id) as users 
FROM 
    companies c 
LEFT JOIN 
    auditing a on c.id=a.company_id 
LEFT JOIN
    users u on c.id=u.company_id
GROUP BY 
    c.id 
HAVING 
    count(u.user_id)>10
LIMIT
    10
```

When I run this it displays an incorrect number of actions.

For example, for the first company in the table it returns:

```
Company 1,111026,111026
```

whereas it should return:

```
Company 1,5093,22
```

I need to get back the number of actions and the number of users for all companies - how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try putting in DISTINCT so that way you aren't counting duplicates

```
SELECT 
    c.company_name,
    count(DISTINCT a.action) as actions,
    count(DISTINCT u.user_id) as users 
FROM 
    companies c 
LEFT JOIN 
    auditing a on c.id=a.company_id 
LEFT JOIN
    users u on c.id=u.company_id
GROUP BY 
    c.id 
HAVING 
    count(u.user_id)>10
LIMIT
    10
```

Comment: DISTINCT has worked a treat on users and it now returns 22 correctly but adding it to actions returns a result of 1151 which is not correct

Comment: @bhttoan then you may have to do your counts separately as the join on users and actions is causing extra results

Comment: Actually just figured out the problem - the action column is a text column and the same actions are being repeated in it hence the count was "wrong" so I changed the column to id which only contains unique values and then did a distinct count on it and it worked fine, thanks!

Comment: @bhttoan oh gotcha! yea that would make sense... I was assuming it was a unique column :)